# Regex: Replace empty space with a dash between the words, on canonical html tag

Tags: notepad++, regex, sublime-text-3

I have this canonical link, but if you look well, there are some empty space on the html link. Those empty space I must replace it with a dash

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/calitatile unui lider.html" />`

**Must Become:**

`<link rel="canonical" href="https://neculaifantanaru.com/calitatile-unui-lider.html" />`

does anyone have any idea how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

**Generic regex for Find:**

`(?-si:FIRST-PART|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!FINAL-PART).)*?\KREGEX-REPLACE`

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?-si:<link rel="canonical" href="https://trinketbox\.ro/|(?!\A)\G)(?s-i:(?!" />).)*?\K\x20`
- Replace with: `-`
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>